# How to initialize an empty associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have an empty object in the API response like the one mentioned below:

```
{
  "sample" : {}
}
```

When I assign $response['sample'] = array(), I get the following response

```
{
  "sample" : []
}
```

Answer (score 6):

{} indicates an object
so you have to use

```
$result = ["sample" => new stdclass()];
```

Answer (score 4):

you must try `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as second argument while using `json_encode` function.

**EDIT**

```
$ar = array("sample" => array());
echo json_encode($ar, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```